# iTunes - Where have Apps gone?

Tags: sync, itunes, mac-app-store

Just noticed that the Apps menu has disappeared from the iTunes menu?

Is it possible I've switched it off or something?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It's gone in 12.7. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=iTunes+12.7 for a whole swathe of similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

They dropped that in [iTunes 12.7](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208075). Apple is suggesting using direct iOS download, but if you prefer to have a local copy of your apps, the latest version of iMazing will let you do that in the free trial. Disclosure: I work with the team.

Only apps which you have already acquired via the App Store can be downloaded and installed. Here’s a detailed article  on [how app managemnet features in iMazing details](https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-manage-apps-without-itunes). It will give you a good idea of how it can help you.